# Get n number of consecutive elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array and an (variable) integer n, I want to create a new array comprising n number of consecutive elements of the array. I have it if n = 2 but I can't figure how to enable variable n:

```
var arr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth" ];
var int = 3;

function consecEls(array, int) {
    newArr = arr.map(function(val, ix, arr) {
        var next = ix+1; // this works if I only needed firstsecond, secondthird, etc. but I need arbitrary # of consecutive els
        // var next = ... ? ... next n els

        var els = arr.slice(arr[ix], int); // or slice(ix, int) ... both return  ["first", "second", "third"]

        if (next !== arr.length) {
            return val + arr[next];
        }
        else { return val; }
    }) // forEach
    return newArr;
}

consecEls(arr, int);
```

Any insight is much appreciated,

================================================

As I mentioned in the comments below, here's my very slightly modified version of @gyre's solution:

```
var arr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth" ];

function map(array, groupSize, callback, context) {
    var i = 0;
    var result = [];
    while (i < array.length) {
        result.push(
          callback.call(context, array.slice(i, i + groupSize), i, array)
        )
        i ++
    }
    return result
}

map(arr, 2, function (e) { 
    return e.join("")
})
```

================================================

ok, one more quick edit: I tweaked slightly further, to eliminate the callback:

```
function map(array, groupSize) {
    var i = 0;
    var result = [];
    while (i < array.length) {
        result.push(array.slice(i, i + groupSize).join(""))
    i ++
    }
    return result
}
map(array, n);
```

Comment: And what would be the expected output from that function ?

Comment: `.map` is not right function for that job. `.map` will return an array of the same size as the original array. Or I don't understand what you want as result.

Comment: the desired output is, e.g., if n = 3, [ firstsecondthird, secondthirdfourth, etc.] ... and as to .map() vs forEach() it doesn't matter if I have to create a new array... Thx

Comment: So you basically want to ***join*** array values on every `n` iteration

Comment: @adeneo yes I suppose so, and I get the hint ... but it's the iterating (within map or forEach) val + n that I'm hung up on

Comment: As Felix noted, `map` is the wrong method, it returns an array of the exact same length as the original

Comment: @adeneo thank you, that's just swell but my question is not .map vs. .forEach (or another array method); it's about getting a variable number of elements within either method

Comment: @WhiskeyT.Foxtrot: I edited my answer, and I think it does what you were looking for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** [@torazaburo's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41072708/7256039) is actually a nicer separation of concerns than the function I had originally. I didn't realize that there was a name for that process of splitting up an array into fixed-length groups. However, here is my alternate implementation of a `partition` function because I think it could be a little cleaner, and include an optional `offset` parameter to allow skipping over the first few elements:

```js
function partition (array, size, offset) {
    offset |= 0
    var result = []
    while (offset < array.length) {
        result.push(array.slice(offset, offset += size))
    }
    return result
}

var arr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth" ],
    example

// Groups of three, joined by spaces
example = partition(arr, 3).map(function (e) { 
    return e.join(' ')
})
console.log(example) //=> ["first second third", "fourth fifth sixth" ]

// A list of pairs
example = partition(arr, 2)
console.log(example) //=> [ ["first", "second"], ["third", "fourth"], ["fifth", "sixth"] ]

// A list of one-element arrays, skipping the first element
example = partition(arr, 1, 1)
console.log(example) //=> [ ["second"], ["third"], ["fourth"], ["fifth"], ["sixth"] ]
```

---

**Original:** Alright, it seems that I may have misunderstood your question the first time around. It looks like your goal is to map over groups of array elements; say, pairs instead of one at a time.

Below is a function `map`, which takes similar arguments to the native `Array#map`. Don't let the function signature intimidate you too much; it's pretty easy to use and you will rarely need to pass more than three parameters.

---

```
function map(array, groupSize, callback, offset, context) {
```

**Parameters:**

1. `array` — The array that you want to map over.
2. `groupSize` — The number of elements that you want to see at a time.
3. `callback` — The mapping function that you pass, which receives **1)** a group of elements, **2)** the index of the first element in the current group, and **3)** the original array.
4. `offset` — The index at which the first group should begin; allows skipping of elements.
5. `context` — Determines what `this` is bound to in your callback.

**Returns:**

An array containing the return values, in order, of the calls made to `callback` for each group of elements.

---

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth" ],
    example

// Groups of three, joined by spaces
example = map(arr, 3, function (e) { 
    return e.join(' ')
})
console.log(example) //=> ["first second third", "fourth fifth sixth" ]

// A list of pairs
example = map(arr, 2, function (e) { 
    return e
})
console.log(example) //=> [ ["first", "second"], ["third", "fourth"], ["fifth", "sixth"] ]


function map(array, groupSize, callback, offset, context) {
    var i = offset | 0,
        result = []
    while (i < array.length) {
        result.push(
          callback.call(context, array.slice(i, i + groupSize), i, array)
        )
        i += groupSize
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: so whether I use .map() or .forEach(), using either var els = arr.slice(arr[ix], int) or var els = arr.arr.slice(ix, int), I still get the same first 3 elements ... I thought, being in a .map() or forEach(), I would be iterating groups of n elements

Comment: Thanks again. Perhaps my OP was not entirely clear; the main thing I couldn't find in the solutions offered was that the 'chunks' were overlapping, i.e., given n elements to group, abc, bcd, cde, etc., whereas several of the solutions returned abc, def, etc. 

I was able to achieve the desired result with very slight mods to your 2nd solution (so I'll give yours the check, Thx). Since this is too much for a comment, I'll edit the OP if I can

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for in the notion of "chunking" or "partitioning". This refers to splitting an array into sub-arrays according to some criteria, often length. There are many partitioning solutions out there; here we use a real simple one. However, note that this will destroy the original array.

Once you have partitioned your input, in your case you want to concatenate the elements of each subarray, so

```js
function partition(array, n) {
  return array.length ? [array.splice(0, n)].concat(partition(array, n)) : [];
}   

var arr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth" ];
var int = 3;

const result = partition(arr, int).map(subarray => subarray.join(''))

console.log(result);
```

Here is a more straight-forward partition implementation:

```
function partition(array, n) {
  let result = [], cnt = 0, sub;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!cnt--) cnt = n, result.push(sub = []);
    sub.push(array[i]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. At my point in newbie-ness I figured some recursion would be applicable, but I don't have my head wrapped around recursion comfortably yet. Your first version returns  ["firstsecondthird", "fourthfifthsixth"], and your second returns [["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], ["fifth", "sixth"]] ... and since I'm going for [ "firstsecondthird", "secondthirdfourth", "thirdfourthfifth" ... I think I could prob figure that from your 2nd version. Thanks for the heads-up re: the terminology 'chunking', 'partitioning'; I will definitely read up on these topics. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`array.slice()` if you want to leave the original array as it is
or
`array.splice()` if you want to remove the items from original array
for both functions you pass in the starting index and number of elements from that starting index on to "select/cut" from the original array

Comment: @gyre, both functions return a "new" array. So they both do what the OP wanted. The difference is that slice() leaves the original array unchanged, whereas splice() removes the items from the original array.
sidenote: splice can also be used to add items to array, but that is not relavant for this question.

Comment: Good point. I guess I had assumed that OP would have wanted the original unchanged, but that might not be the case.